# How to find a control in a row and bind it to data

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a gridview and in the gridview i got a item template as follows

```
        <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProductNames"> 
        </asp:DropDownList> 
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Now on every row in the gridview i need to bind this to the data, but i am having trouble finding it and binding it to the data.

The gridview has 4 templatefields with 1 itemtemplate within each template field like this

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center" > 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" /> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />   
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Products" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center" > 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProductNames"> 
                </asp:DropDownList> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  />   
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center" > 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="image" /> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <ItemStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center"  />   
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:CheckBox Text="Active" runat="server" ID="active" /> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <ItemStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And I am trying to bind the drop down as follows

```
    protected void Grid_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // Bind Products
        Product productManager = new Product();
        TList<Product> dsProduct= productManager.GetAll();

        DropDownList ddlProducts = Grid.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0].FindControl("ddlProductNames") as DropDownList;
        if (dsProduct != null)
        {
            DataView dvProduct = new DataView(dsProduct.ToDataSet(true).Tables[0]);
            dvProduct.Sort = "name asc";
            ddlProducts.DataSource = dvBrand;
            ddlProducts.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlProducts.DataValueField = "productId";
            ddlProducts.DataBind();
            ListItem li = new ListItem("No Product Selected", "0");
            ddlProducts.Items.Insert(0, li); 
        }
    }
```

I am getting a out of index in the line             `DropDownList ddlProducts = Grid.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0].FindControl("ddlProductNames") as DropDownList;` I am  learning this process so i would appreciate some help in terms of what i am doing wrong and what i need to change. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to find controls in a TemplateField. You also need to exclude the header-row:

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        DropDownList ddlProducts = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlProductNames");
        ddlProducts.DataSource = someDataSource;
        ddlProducts.DataTextField = "name";
        ddlProducts.DataValueField = "productId";
        ddlProducts.DataBind();
    }
}
```

You also don't need to call `productManager.GetAll()` for every row in the Grid. You only need to get the products for the current Row. If the source is the same for every row, you should create it before you bind the GridView as member-variable. Then you don't need to retrieve the same data for each row.